# Views acessando outros controllers

Tags: mvc, engenharia-de-software

Digamos que eu tenha a classe `Veiculo` e a classe `Fabricante`. Cada veículo possui um fabricante como atributo, dentre outros atributos.

Tenho as *views* para manter (cadastrar, editar e excluir) e buscar veículo e também fabricante.

Cada classe modelo tem seu *controller* (decidi criar 1 controle por modelo, ao invés de criar um controle por *view*). Ou seja, a classe `controlVeiculo` será acessada por mais de uma *view* e terá os métodos

```
+listarVeiculos()

+salvarVeiculo(Veiculo v)

+editarVeiculo(Veiculo v)

+excluirVeiculo(Veiculo v)

(...)
```

Que por sua vez acessa as classes DAO. Bem como a classe `controlFabricante` terá os mesmos métodos para fabricante.

Quando eu chamar a *view* para cadastrar veículo, por exemplo, vou precisar listar os fabricantes já cadastrados no banco para a escolha do usuário.
Essa lista de fabricantes deve vir da onde?

- crio uma instância do `controlFabricante` dentro da `viewVeiculo` e chamo o método normalmente?
- deixo a minha `viewVeiculo` somente acessando o seu controle (`controlVeiculo`) e crio um método no `controlVeículo` para acessar a `DAOFabricante`?
- deixo a minha `viewVeiculo` somente acessando o seu controle (`controlVeiculo`) e, ao invés de criar um método no `controlVeículo`, eu crio uma instância do `controlFabricante` dentro de `controlVeiculo` e chamo o método entre os *controllers* (já que já tem um método definido no outro controle, evitando duplicar métodos)
- alguma outra sugestão?

Comment: Você instancia um model de fabricante e chama o método para listar elas,

Comment: Sem passar por nenhum controle mesmo? Instancio o fabricante dentro da viewVeiculo?

Comment: Sim, sem nenhum controlador, a não ser que você esteva validando dados no controlador, pois normalmente o modelo é responsável por validar e salvar/editar/apagar/buscar dados na persistência. E não, você cria uma instância no controlador do veículo, no método listarVeiculos, assim você pega o resultado dessa instância e envia para a view

Comment: Blz, valeu pela ajuda!

Comment: @GustavoBelczak A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 5):

Vou responder baseado no que tem na pergunta. Pode ser que tenha outras informações que me faça pensar diferente.

Acho que não entendeu o MVC. Você não precisa ter uma relação de um para um com nada, **o MVC existe justamente para não ter o um para um, se tiver então não deve usar o MVC**.

Crie os modelos que precisa para manipular os dados, possivelmente fazendo a persistência.

Crie as visões que precisa para apresentar os dados, possivelmente cada uma será uma tela ou parte de uma tela, seja ela como for mostrada para o usuário.

Crie os controladores que precisa para fazer operações diversas. Um controlador não precisa estar ligado nem à visão, nem ao modelo, ele deve executar algo que faça sentido estar em uma unidade única.

Você pode ter um controlador só para o que deseja. Ou pode ter a operação que deseja dentro de um controlador já existente, se fizer sentido.

Tire da cabeça essa relação e tudo começa clarificar.

Em geral o *controller* só deve fazer operações técnicas da aplicação. Ele deve fazer a montagem do que é necessário para oferecer para a *view*, normalmente pedindo dados para o *model*.

Quem deve fornecer dados é o modelo.

> Essa lista de fabricantes deve vir da onde?

Do modelo de fabricantes.

> crio uma instância do `controlFabricante` dentro da `viewVeiculo` e chamo o método normalmente?

Não, as camadas devem ser independentes, e a *view* deve receber dados passados pelo *controller*.

> deixo a minha `viewVeiculo` somente acessando o seu controle (`controlVeiculo`) e crio um método no `controlVeículo` para acessar a `DAOFabricante`?

Mais ou menos isso. Cria uma instância do *model* dentro do *controller* para receber os dados, tratar e enviar para a *view*.

> deixo a minha `viewVeiculo` somente acessando o seu controle (`controlVeiculo`) e, ao invés de criar um método no controlVeículo, eu crio uma instância do `controlFabricante` dentro de `controlVeiculo` e chamo o método entre os *controllers* (já que já tem um método definido no outro controle, evitando duplicar métodos)

Não digo que não possa fazer isso, mas precisa ver se faz sentido.

Talvez precise fazer algo diferente disso, mas em algo genérico, sem detalhes fica difícil dizer.

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas!